# Git distributed workflow with submodules

Tags: git, workflow, distributed, git-submodules

Say I have a super-project with N sub-modules. Which I have created following this guide: [Git Submodule Tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/g/i/t/GitSubmoduleTutorial_c489.html)

So I have public repositories for all sub modules plus a public repo for the super project, all this in a remote host: `machine1/path/to/public/repos.git`. These I will call my public repos.

Now, user X clones the super project from my public repo and pulls everything to his private repo. All references in his local `.git/config` and `.gitmodules` point to my public repos.

I want user X to have his own public repository so we can use the distributed workflow described here: [Git Distributed Workflows](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html)

This way user X and I can push our local changes to our own public repos and then pull changes from each other's public repos. I want to avoid both of us having to push to the same public repos.

Since `.gitmodules` in X's local repo points to my public repos, X needs to change the ulr's so they point to his public repos. Please bear in mind that .gitmodules is commited, so we'd run into a conflict if X commits & publishes `.gitmodules` after modifying it to reference his public repos and then I pull changes from his public repo (my local `.gitmodules` would be referencing his public repos instead of mine whichs is not the desired result).

So what do you think would be the best alternative:

- Remove `.gitmodules` from the repository's tree and add it to `.gitignore` so it is not tracked anymore.
- Keep `.gitmodules` unstaged. I'm not sure why but this seems to me a bad a idea.
- Use `git --update-index assume-unchanged .gitmodules`

Any of these options have the disadvantage that `.gitmodules` would be wiped out if one runs `git clean` or discard all untracked files.

How can I keep the changes in X's `.gitmodules` to reference his own public repo permanently and not have to worry about accidentally wipe the configuration out, or pulling unwanted changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this with adding additional remotes to your submoules. Also, git submodule remote urls from the containing repo only get synced when you add the --init option. Nothing is stopping you from doing a git submodule add, update, init and then changing the url in the repo for that remote. Subsequent submodule updates won't change that url unless you add the --init opition.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to accept this answer at the moment I first read it I didn't understand it, now it seems obvious.